# Issue with drawing routes on Windows Phone 8.0 maps - 0x8004231C

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, maps

I want to create an app which shows the route from my location to some desired point. The problem is it sometimes works (for some locations the route is drawn) but in some cases I get this error:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004231C): Excepion from HRESULT: 0x8004231C.
```

In addition I followed a tutorial found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244363%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Here's my code:

```
private async void GetCoordinates()
    {
        // Get the phone's current location.
        Geolocator MyGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        MyGeolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 5;
        Geoposition MyGeoPosition = null;
        try
        {
            MyGeoPosition = await MyGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            MyCoordinates.Add(new GeoCoordinate(MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Longitude));
            Mapka.Center = new GeoCoordinate(MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);

        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Location is disabled in phone settings or capabilities are not checked.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Something else happened while acquiring the location.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        Mygeocodequery = new GeocodeQuery();
        Mygeocodequery.QueryCompleted += Mygeocodequery_QueryCompleted;
        Mygeocodequery.SearchTerm = txt1.Text;
        Mygeocodequery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);

        Mygeocodequery.QueryAsync();


            }
    void Mygeocodequery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            MyQuery = new RouteQuery();
            MyCoordinates.Add(e.Result[0].GeoCoordinate);
            MyQuery.Waypoints = MyCoordinates;
            MyQuery.QueryCompleted += MyQuery_QueryCompleted;
            MyQuery.RouteOptimization = RouteOptimization.MinimizeDistance;
            MyQuery.QueryAsync();

            Mygeocodequery.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());

        }
    }

    void MyQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {

            Route MyRoute = e.Result;
            MapRoute MyMapRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);
            Mapka.AddRoute(MyMapRoute);
            Mapka.SetView(MyMapRoute.Route.BoundingBox);
            MessageBox.Show(MyMapRoute.Route.LengthInMeters.ToString());
            MyQuery.Dispose();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());

        }
 }
```

Maybe someone had similar problem and can help?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
    GeoCoordinate myPosition = null;
    MapRoute MyMapRoute = null;
    RouteQuery route = null;

    private void getRouteTo(GeoCoordinate myPosition, GeoCoordinate destination)
    {
        if (MyMapRoute != null)
        {
            map.RemoveRoute(MyMapRoute);
            MyMapRoute = null;
            route = null;
        }
        route = new RouteQuery()
        {
            TravelMode = TravelMode.Driving,
            Waypoints = new List<GeoCoordinate>()
            {
                myPosition, 
                destination
            },
            RouteOptimization = RouteOptimization.MinimizeTime
        };
        route.QueryCompleted += routeQuery_QueryCompleted;
        route.QueryAsync();
    }
    void routeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            Route MyRoute = e.Result;

            MyMapRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);
            map.AddRoute(MyMapRoute);
            route.Dispose();
        }
    }
```